# Find if valid full backup exists for SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-backups

I'm wanting to find for a given database whether or not a valid full backup exists that can be used for differential or trans log backups. Of course it's not enough that a full backup exists, it must be able to begin a chain. To this end I want to eliminate those backups created before a recovery model change, as well as copy only backups. TSQL only please. No GUI explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the source from Ola Hallengren's backup script and came up with this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN last_log_backup_lsn IS NULL THEN 0
             ELSE 1
        END AS log_backup_possible
FROM    sys.database_recovery_status
WHERE   database_id = DB_ID('foobar');
```

A log backup can be taken if the last_log_backup_lsn is not null. Also, a differential backup is good enough to start taking log backups.

In other news, I alluded to Ola Hallengren's excellent maintenance scripts above. Specifically, he has a parameter in the backup stored procedure (@ChangeBackupType) that takes care of all of this for you (so you don't have to re-invent the wheel).

Comment: Ben, that's awesome. I'm not sure if I'd want that diff without a full, but it's interesting to note. Thanks very much.

Comment: Ooh don't worry about that - you can't take a diff without a full. I'm just saying that if you already have a full, no need to take another one just to start a log chain; a diff will suffice for that purpose.

Comment: Also, if you find that this answers your question, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? It helps others to know that was indeed what you were looking for. Also, it boosts my fake internet points a little. ;)

Comment: I see what you're saying about the diff now. Thanks again, Ben!